# Custom UITableViewCell on Grouped UITableView doesn't look right

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS application and I have a `UITableView` with custom cells.

This is the custom `UITableViewCell` **XIB**.

[image]

Note: the tick icon will be show on edit mode.

The `UITableView` is grouped. And I don't why the table is shown this way:

[image]

Do I have to make `UITableViewCell` **xib** smaller? Or, How can I fix this problem.

I want to add more space between the name and the `UITableView` left border (the icon will be shown later, on edit mode).

I've found this [tutorial](http://blog.arunstephens.com/2010/03/07/width-of-grouped-uitableviewcell/), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: the autoresizing of the label would be much more interesting. It's probably wrong.

Comment: No, this is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, make it smaller or leave 10 pixels on the right and left on your custom cell. On iPhone grouped table view cell width is 300 pixels. Good Luck!

Comment: I've made it smaller than 300 pixels and it doesn't look right.